# Creating a Compilation Unit with type bindings

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I am working with the [AST API](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rtnlhelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FAST.html) in java, and I am trying to create a [Compilation Unit](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rtnlhelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FAST.html) with type bindings. I wrote the following code:

```
private static CompilationUnit parse(ICompilationUnit unit) {
 ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
 parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
 parser.setSource(unit);
 parser.setResolveBindings(true);
 CompilationUnit compiUnit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
 return compiUnit;
}
```

Unfortunately, when I run this code in debug mode and inspect `compiUnit` I find that `compiUnit.ast.resolver.isRecoveringBindings` is false.
Can anyone think of a reason why it wouldn't be `true`, as I specified it to be?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up two pieces of the API: binding resolving and binding recovery.  From the JavaDoc for `setBindingsRecovery`:

```
void org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.setBindingsRecovery(boolean enabled)

Requests that the compiler should perform bindings recovery. When bindings recovery is enabled the compiler returns incomplete bindings.

Default to false.

This should be set to true only if bindings are resolved. It has no effect if there is no binding resolution.

Parameters:
enabled true if incomplete bindings are expected, and false if only complete bindings are expected.
```

So, yes.  It is expected that bindings recovery is set to false because that is the default.  However, since you explicitly set bindings to be resolved, that should be set to true in the `AST` object.  You should check the method `AST.hasBindingsResolved()` to see if you can get your bindings.

To be clear: bindings resolution is about getting the parser/compiler to calculate type bindings as the AST is being created, while bindings recovery is about enabling bindings to be partially computed.  Honestly, I'm not exactly sure what bindings recovery helps with, but I am fairly certain that it is not something that you need.

Comment: Ok, first of all that info was really helpful for me to understand better whats going on.
Now I am left with a new question: with the recovery enabled, will I be able to get bindings of an `ASTNode` I got as a result of using `ASTNode.copySubtree(asttree, astnode)`?

Comment: I don't know.  Why don't you try it out? :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it seems that either `compiUnit.ast.resolver.isRecoveringBindings` dosen't mean what it seems to mean, or it is simply incorrect (The java AST API is not the most stable one...).
Either way, working with the Compilation Unit later on revealed that it does resolve type binding when asked to.

The original problem which raised my question was that I got a NullPointerException when trying to fetch `arg.resolveTypeBinding().getName();`. This **does** mean that `arg` doesn't have bindings. However, The reason for that was that it was not part of the original AST created by the java environment, but the result of  `arg = ASTNode.copySubtree(classAst, arg2);`.
So instead, I called `resolveTypeBinding().getName()` on `arg2` rather than on `arg`, which gave me the wanted result.